# Cannot use debug in eclipse for man

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, darwin

I have been trying to debug C++ through eclipse on mac. I have already installed gdb through HomeBrew, and have already codesigned it through a certificate I have created myself. After that, I have already restarted my computer.

But when I run it now, it shows as follow:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 31498: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n
(please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))    
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 31498: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n
(please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 sudo /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

instead of

```
  /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

in the GDB debugger settings in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message. You need to make sure gdb is Codesignned as in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html

It's kind of painful since you need a restart, but it works all the time.